# Using LLDB for debugging C

Tags: c, macos, debugging, lldb

I'm writing a small C library for some basic polygon operations and I'm trying to use LLDB from the command line for debugging.  I am able to run LLDB with my compiled test runner, but I can only see assembly instructions and not C code as I step through.

I've compiled my library and test runner with the -g flag as shown here in this Makefile:

```
#Define compiler flags
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Werror

#Define objects
OBJECTS = MASClip.o MASGraph.o MASClipTest.o

tests : $(OBJECTS) 
    cc $(CFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o tests 

MASClip.o : MASClip.h MASClip.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c MASClip.c

MASGraph.o : MASGraph.h MASGraph.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c MASGraph.c

MASClipTest.o : MASClipTest.c
    cc $(CFLAGS) -c MASClipTest.c

test :
    make
    make clean
    ./tests

.PHONY : clean

clean :
    rm *.o
```

I can set breakpoints by function name so I don't understand why the code is not displayed.

I've searched around, but I don't see that I'm doing anything different from what the tutorials and other questions say.  I must be missing something obvious.

Also, I realise I could just do this in Xcode, but when I write straight C I like to use VIM and it would be nice to be able to use LLDB from the command line.

How do I get LLDB to display the actual C code when debugging?

Comment: idk maybe you need the cflags for each object? or you are actually getting an error, and some of the objects aren't rebuilt?

Comment: Is `cc` invoking `gcc`?  As far as I know, `-g` is only recognized by `gcc` and `g++`.

Comment: I believe cc invokes the clang compiler which does have a -g flag for debugging info.

Comment: I'm assuming you did a `make clean` then ran `make` again to ensure all the objects were rebuilt with debug info?

Comment: I just compiled from source files without compiling into objects first and it worked.  Obviously it's not possible to walk through the code of a precompiled object file.  Is that correct?

Comment: You can only debug a final executable, not individual object files.

Comment: I also don't see a -O0 in the CFLAGS. While it is possible to debug optimized code, your results may not match source code. If you're just trying to get started, it is usually a good idea to debug unoptimized code.

Comment: I tried with the -O0 flag, but that still didn't work.  When I compiled a list of *.c files it worked.  Obviously there must be some way of debugging with .o files, but I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 0):

On OS X debug info is stored in .o files.  The debugger refers back to the .o files using a "debug map" in the executable.  Looks like you are deleting the .o files before you try to debug, so there's no debug information for the debugger.

Either leave the .o files in place when you debug, or run the `dsymutil` tool on the executable to produce a linked debug output file (.dSYM.)  If you put the dSYM next to the executable (or anywhere that Spotlight searches) then lldb will find it automatically.

Note that if you just give the compiler a list of .c files, it will make a dSYM for you automatically - since it will delete the .o files when it is done - so that debugging is still possible.